# How to open/automate VmWare Horizon using robot framework

Tags: robotframework, vmware

I'm trying to automate an application hosted in AWS and I need to launch the application via VMWare Horizon using Robot Framework.

For launching the URL and credentials I have used RPA.Browser.Selenium libraries and code looks like below

```
Create WebDriver  Chrome  executable_path =${driver_path_location}
Go To             ${url}
Input text        ${username_fields}       xxx
Input text        ${password_field}        xxx
Click Element     ${submit}
```

After this, the URL cloud environment is selected and encountered with the below window alert. I have tried to click the **Open VMware Horizon** button   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdpXY.png using RPA.Windows.Desktop keywords(mouse click and Send keys) but it's not getting clicked and due to environmental restrictions, I cannot use Sikulilibray or AutoIt library. Could someone please guide me on how to open a VMware Horizon using robot framework. I'm new to robotframework and totally stuck with this issue. Thanks.
[VmWare horizon pop up][1]

Comment: Please type up the error in here

Comment: I'm not getting any error, when I used below keywords
"""RPA.Desktop.Windows  Mouse click   x-coordinate  y-coordinate""",
 the  log says it has clicked in the coordinate but VMhorizon didn't open

Answer (score 0):

In the [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert) there is a keyword called `Handle Alert` which should be able to do this for you. You won't be able to click on any browser alerts normally as they are specifically designed so. The default action by the keyword is `Accept` which should in this case mean the "Open VMWare Horizon Client".

If the keyword does not work for you, you may need to set the "Always Allow" on and simply manually prepare the test execution whenever your browser cache is emptied.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the Handle Alert keyword but it is throwing" No Alert Present" in the log. I guess it's a window alert that cannot be handled using SeleniumLibrary keywords

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case with Robot Framework, but if you are using web-only automation like Selenium this is likely not possible as it launches outside the browser.  You wouldn't be able to automate VMWare Horizon Client with Selenium anyway.

However, if launching is the only requirement, you can likely set the automation browser configuration to a manual location, manually click "Always Allow" and then the prompt will not appear during automation—Horizon will launch immediately.

Unfortunately, this solution is not maintainable in the long run.